# Probability of G(4, 1/2) random graph being connected

Tags: probability-theory, random-graphs

Suppose we have a random undirected graph G(4, 1/2), i.e. the probability of any two of the four total vertices being connected is 1/2.

how to find the probability that  Probability (G(4, 1/2) is connected)=?

Can someone give me idea how to do it.

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 2):

Any graph with at most $2$ edges is disconnected, any graph with at least $4$ edges is connected (since there are only $3$ edges among any $3$ of the vertices). Thus you can do most of the work by summing probabilities for numbers of edges without dealing with specific configurations. Then you just have to consider which configurations of $3$ edges make the graph connected and count them.

*More explicit solution in response to the comments:*

The probability that there are $k$ edges is $P(K=k)=2^{-6}\binom6k$. You can either add these probabilities for $k$ from $4$ to $6$, or use the symmetry $P(K\lt3)=P(K\gt3)$ to get

$$
P(K\gt3)=\frac{1-P(K=3)}2=\frac{1-\frac{20}{64}}2=\frac{11}{32}\;.
$$

To this you need to add the probability of getting a connected graph with $3$ edges. You correctly counted $16$ connected cases ($\binom63=20$ cases minus the $4$ in which all $3$ edges are among $3$ vertices), so this probability is $\frac{16}{64}$, for a total of

$$
\frac{11}{32}+\frac{16}{64}=\frac{19}{32}\;.
$$

Comment: @ jorki, Thanks but i couldn't understand how to make a general  formula to compute it.

Comment: @Maaz: What do you mean by a "general formula"? You asked about a specific case; I showed how to compute it for the specific case. You didn't ask for a general formula. Which part do you want to generalise?

Comment: @jorki Sorry i didn't express well enough myself, i just asked about how the complete calculation will look like since i just got 16 cases on which 4 vertices and 3 edges can be connected and 4 which are not. But i still have a doubt about how to calculate the whole probability, I know that with 4 edges and 4 vertices probability of being connected is one and with 4 vertices and 0,1 or 2 edges the probability of being connected is 0 but how can i join them all in a single expression for the total probability. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Maaz: OK, I added a more explicit solution. (I hadn't done so originally because you asked to "give you an idea" how to do it.)

Comment: @ Jorki! Thanks a lot! can you please tell me about that if in bionomial random graph model G(n, lnn/n^2) it obeys  Zer0-one law or not?  I know that lnn/n is a threshold function for connectivity and for lnn/n zer0-one law doesn't hold but what's about lnn/n^2?

Comment: @Maaz: I can't decypher that. [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)'s a reference and tutorial for typesetting math on this site. As far as I can tell, that sounds like a completely different question. Please ask one question per post (or closely related questions); comments aren't meant for new questions.